# jquery different fade for different hover

Tags: jquery, navbar, fade

I would like to make different fadein and fadeout to "li" elements in "navbar". I mean: if mouse enter or mouse leave a "li", do fade. but if I move from one "li" to another "li", dont do fade. Is it possible? thank you very much for every answer.

```js
var opened = 0;
$("li").mouseenter(function(e) {
  opened = 1;
  if (opened == 1) {
    $(this).find(".menu-full").fadeIn(0);
  } else {
    $(this).find(".menu-full").fadeIn(300);
  }
});

$("li").mouseleave(function(e) {
  opened = 0;
  if (opened == 1) {
    $(this).find(".menu-full").fadeOut(0);
  } else {
    $(this).find(".menu-full").fadeOut(300);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">News <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <div class="menu-full">
      ...
    </div>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Reviews <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <div class="menu-full">
      ...
    </div>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Media</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Artist</a></li>
</ul>
```

I would like that when the mouse enters or exits the "li" element, a fade300 starts. while if the mouse passes from one element "li" to the other, the fade does not start.

Comment: Make the fadeIn and out on the list container such as `<ol>`

Comment: The answer to your too broad question; yes.  It's possible.

Comment: Hi McRoy, welcome on SO. Please use your "answer" to edit this question... because you did not answer: you have only added more information to help us to understand your problem. BTW, where is `.full` element in your HTML code?

Comment: sorry.. old code. ".full" was the old class of LI element. I corrected the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I well understood your question, you could create a class (and call it for example `enter`) and put it in your `<ul>` when you enter on `<ul>`, then remove it when you leave.

In addition, you can create a variable that tracks the `<li>` in which you're in mouseenter/mouseleave: when you are passing through `<li>`s you can do a simple fadeIn with 0 seconds, while if you go out of the `<ul>` make a fadeout with 300ms.

I added some CSS only to help you to understand when you enter in `<ul>` & `<li>`. You can remove them.

```js
$(function() {
    var menuFull;

    $("li").hover(function(e){
        var $this = $(this);
        menuFull = $(".menu-full", $this);

        if($this.closest("ul").hasClass("enter")) {
          $(".menu-full").fadeOut(0);
          menuFull.fadeIn(0);
        }
    });

    $("ul").hover(function(){
        var $this = $(this);

        $this.toggleClass("enter");
        menuFull.fadeToggle(300);
    });
  });
```

```css
/* Start styles for demo */
*{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
body{
    display:flex;
    height: 100vh;
    align-items: center;
}
ul{
    margin:auto;
    float:left;
    min-height: 1px;
    background-color:#cccccc;
    padding:0;
}
li{
    padding:10px;
    list-style: none;
}
/* end styles for demo */


.menu-full{
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
   <li><a href="#">News <span class="caret"></span></a>
       <div class="menu-full">
            menu-full
       </div>
   </li>
    <li><a href="#">Reviews <span class="caret"></span></a>
           <div class="menu-full">
             menu-full
           </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Media</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Artist</a></li>
</ul>
```

Hope it helps.